# how can i use java Save All Resources in chrome headless on linux server without any gui?

Tags: java, linux, google-chrome-headless, save-as

I want Save  a HTML page including all referenced resources (css, js, images…).

I try to use `wget -r http://szhong.4399.com/4399swf/upload_swf/ftp29/gamehwq/20190912/10/index.htm`

it can download html and js , but images load by script.

and I try to use HtmlUnit save page,I get the same result like wget.

I think I should eval js and get all http request and save they to file ?

when I use  [Save All Resources](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-all-resources/abpdnfjocnmdomablahdcfnoggeeiedb?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) in chrome , it's run well.

so , I want to use chrome headless to finish my work.